# Deleting all rows from a dynamically created table

Tags: asp.net

I have a page where I am dynamically creating an asp.net table.  At some point based on user input I need to be able to delete all the rows in the table and recreate them from scratch.  When I try to loop through the table rows and remove them one by one I get the following error.  "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.  "

Is there another way to do this?  This code is the first thing in the function that creates the dynamic rows.

```
foreach (TableRow tr in ChecklistQuestionTable.Rows)
        {
            ChecklistQuestionTable.Rows.Remove(tr);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ChecklistQuestionTable.Rows.Clear();
```

See [`HtmlTableRowCollection.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablerowcollection.clear.aspx) on MSDN.

> Use this method to remove all HtmlTableRow objects from the HtmlTableRowCollection collection and reset the Count property to 0.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest things are the hardest to find.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `Cast<TableRow>()`:

```
foreach (TableRow tr in ChecklistQuestionTable.Rows.Cast<TableRow>())
```

In general, you can't modify the same collection that you're iterating over in the `foreach`. You can use tricks like `Cast()` and `ToList()` to get a discrete collection that mirrors the starting state of the original, then you can modify the original collection.

Comment: The error is no a type error. It is happening because you can't remove items from a collection while iterating over it.

Comment: The Cast() isn't to address a type exception. It's to get a duplicate collection for iterating over so that the original collection (Table.Rows) can be modified.
But your answer is better.

Comment: Fair enough. But copying the collection just so you could iterate over it is very wasteful.

Comment: In this case, absolutely. In general though, if you need to selectively remove some items from the collection, then no. Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: I appreciate you coming back to remove your downvote. Thank you.